# Android - Add limit to random method using a variable in a class that extends View

Tags: android, seekbar

Well, I can't set the value of the limit when receiving a random number by using a variable with the max limit.

I get the limit by the method seekBarValue.

Them I add the value to make the limit when I call color.nextInt(value); And it crashes there, I've no idea what is happening. I can insert a number, the value variable is a integer value, so I don't see where the problem is.

The seekBarValue method is called before

```
public class Draw extends View 
{
    public Draw(Context context) 
    {
        super(context);
    }

    Paint prop = new Paint();
    Random color = new Random();
    int value;

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();

        int oriwidth = 0;
        int oriheight = 0;      

        for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++) 
        {
            int red = color.nextInt(value);//crashes here
            int green = color.nextInt(value);
            int blue = color.nextInt(value);

            prop.setARGB(255, red, green, blue);
            canvas.drawRect(oriwidth += 10, oriheight += 10, width -= 10, height -= 10, prop);
        }

    public int seekBarValue (int seekValue)
    {
        value=seekValue;
        return value;
    }
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: What crash? Any error output? What is the value of value when it crashes?

Comment: @Averroes I don't have the output here because I'm in school now. But it crashes when the max value is set. If put in numbers for example 50 it will generate numbers between 0 and 49. But I think it's the same thing to say that value variable is equal to 50. It will do the same thing I think. But it crashes when the limit is set.

Comment: what is the error which you get?

Comment: @Pratik I don't have the log here, but it just crashes when I set the limit.

Comment: what is the limit which you are talking about?

Comment: @Pratik This limit color.nextInt(value); this will generate a value between 0 and value-1. It's supposed to do it but it crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're never calling `seekBarValue` method, therefore variable `value` keeps `0` as default value, so you're calling

```
color.nextInt(0);
```

which throws an `IllegalArgumentException`. `nextInt` param must be greater than `0`.

---

**EDIT**

To avoid the exception, try these changes.-

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if (value > 0) {
        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();

        int oriwidth = 0;
        int oriheight = 0;      

        for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++) 
        {
            int red = color.nextInt(value);//crashes here
            int green = color.nextInt(value);
            int blue = color.nextInt(value);

            prop.setARGB(255, red, green, blue);
            canvas.drawRect(oriwidth += 10, oriheight += 10, width -= 10, height -= 10, prop);
        }
    }
}
```

Or just make sure that `value` is greater than `0`

```
value = Math.max(value, 1);
```

Also, you'll need to `invalidate` the view after setting new value, in order to `onDraw` method be called. If you're manually calling `onDraw` from your activity (as I'm guessing), please, don't.

```
public int setValue(int value)
{
    this.value = value;
    invalidate();
    return value;
}
```

Comment: I don't know, I call the method seekBarValue before call onDraw. And I do that on the MainActivity which it's not here.

Comment: Where? I can't see it in your code snippet. Have you debugged stepped by step to evaluate `value` just before calling `nextInt`?

Comment: Besides, I don't see the point in `seekBarValue` method. Why not just assigning with value = 7?

Comment: I call the methods on the MainActivity which is not here. And I call seekBarValue before onDraw method.

Comment: I want to adjust the limit of 0 to 255 using the seekbar. I don't want to adjust it programmatically.

Comment: Well, chances are that there's a first call to `onDraw` before you actually set value. I edited my answer with a possible solution

Comment: I will have a try after get home. I alert you after try it.

Comment: Well, it's done! Thanks! You were right the variable value was 0 because it wasn't been called. Thank you very much!